# How to split data from MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I try to make horizontally report, as this illustration below :

```
   NO | ITEMS NAME | 01 June | 02 June  | 03 June
    1 | Paper A4   |    3    |    4     |    5
    2 | Pencil     |    0    |    3     |    1
```

I've done the query call from MySQL in the model, like :

```
        $this->db->select('namatoko, GROUP_CONCAT(DAY(tgl_inpt) ORDER BY tgl_inpt ASC) as tgl, GROUP_CONCAT(omz ORDER BY tgl_inpt ASC) as mny');
        $this->db->from('mzharian');
        $this->db->join('toko','toko.idtoko = mzharian.toko');
        $this->db->where('MONTH(tgl_inpt) = MONTH(NOW()) AND YEAR(tgl_inpt) = YEAR(NOW())');
        $this->db->group_by('namatoko');

        $omz = $this->db->get();
        return $omz;
```

and the result like what I want.

But the problem now comes up maybe from the controller or the view, I don't really sure because while I'm using these codes to call the data to view it doesn't appear as what I want above. 
Here my view page codes :

```
     <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($omz)) { 
      $tgl [] = $row->tgl;
      $money [] = $row->mny;
      $split = array_combine(explode(',', $tgl),explode(',', $money)); ?>

      <tr>
           <td><?php echo $row->namatoko ?></td>
           <?php foreach($row as $v) { echo $split[$v] ? '<td>' .$split[$v].'</td> ':'' ; } ?>
      </tr>
     <?php }; ?>
```

And here is my Controller page codes :

```
        $data['omz'] = $this->Model_omzet->loadomzet();
        $data['datcb'] = $this->Model_omzet->datacb();
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('omzet',$data);
```

Causing an error like this :
`mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given`. Can anybody here help me find the solution?

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_row()` needs as parameter a result set identifier returned by `mysqli_query()`, `mysqli_store_result()` or `mysqli_use_result()`. You are currently feeding it with object `$omz`. Check what happens in `$this->db` and `var_dump($omz)` to identify how to retrieve the result-set identifier you need.

Comment: Something like: `if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) { while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {`

Answer (score 0):

You could return the `omz` result as object from the *model*, and ensure that it's not empty :

```
    $this->db->select('namatoko, GROUP_CONCAT(DAY(tgl_inpt) ORDER BY tgl_inpt ASC) as tgl, GROUP_CONCAT(omz ORDER BY tgl_inpt ASC) as mny');
    $this->db->from('mzharian');
    $this->db->join('toko','toko.idtoko = mzharian.toko');
    $this->db->where('MONTH(tgl_inpt) = MONTH(NOW()) AND YEAR(tgl_inpt) = YEAR(NOW())');
    $this->db->group_by('namatoko');

    $omz = $this->db->get();
    if ($omz->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $omz->result();
    }
```

Then add validation on the *view* :

```
<?php 
    if (!empty($omz))
    {
        foreach($omz as $row){
        $tgl [] = $row->tgl;
        $money [] = $row->mny;
        $split = array_combine(explode(',', $tgl),explode(',', $money));
?>

<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row->namatoko ?></td>
    <?php foreach($row as $v) { echo $split[$v] ? '<td>' .$split[$v].'</td> ':'' ; } ?>
</tr>

<?php
        }
    }
?>
```